# At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query by Use Specification and Sort

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While using the JPA interface `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, I created the following code but it throws an error: "At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query".

The invoke code

```java
@Override
public Result findSightsWithConditions(String cityId, Map<String, String> filter_map) {
  //scoreOrder priceOrder minScore maxScore minPrice maxPrice
  Specification<Sight> specification = new Specification<Sight>() {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Sight> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
      List<Predicate> predicates = Lists.newArrayList();
      //predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("cityId"), cityId));
      if (null != filter_map.get("maxScore")) {
        double max = Integer.parseInt(filter_map.get("maxScore"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("score"), max));
      }
      if (null != filter_map.get("maxPrice")) {
        double max = Integer.parseInt(filter_map.get("maxPrice"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("price"), max));
      }
      if (null != filter_map.get("minScore")) {
        double min = Double.parseDouble(filter_map.get("minScore"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("score"), min));
      }

      if (null != filter_map.get("minPrice")) {
        double min = Double.parseDouble(filter_map.get("minPrice"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("price"), min));
      }
      return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    }
  };
  Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
  String scoreOrder = filter_map.get("scoreOrder");
  String priceOrder = filter_map.get("priceOrder");

  if (scoreOrder != null) {
    // 1 ASE 2DESC
    sort = sort.and(new Sort(Integer.parseInt(scoreOrder) == 1 ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, "score"));
  }
  if (priceOrder != null) {
    sort = sort.and(new Sort(Integer.parseInt(scoreOrder) == 1 ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, "price"));
  }

  List<Sight> sights = sightDao.findAllByCityId(cityId, specification, sort);
  List<SightSimpleVO> sightSimpleVOS = sights.stream().map(sight -> {
    SightSimpleVO vo = new SightSimpleVO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(sight, vo, "pics", "labels");
    vo.setPics(StringUtil.getList(sight.getPics(), ","));
    vo.setLabels(StringUtil.getList(sight.getLabels(), ","));
    return vo;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return Result.success().message("success!").withData(sightSimpleVOS);
}
```

Repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface SightRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Sight, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    List<Sight> findAllByCityId(String cityIds, Specification<Sight> specification, Sort var1);

}
```

I just want to obtain the results under dynamic condition. The Exception message is as following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$CriteriaQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createQueryParameterSetter$1(ParameterBinderFactory.java:139)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createSetters$0(ParameterBinderFactory.java:131)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createCriteriaBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.getBinder(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:248)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy159.findAllByCityId(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The problem is your code uses `Sort` and JpaSpecification `thinks` its part of query. You need to define `Pageable`. Look this example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687061/spring-data-jpa-method-query-with-paging-gives-me-an-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687061/spring-data-jpa-method-query-with-paging-gives-me-an-error)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code should read `implements JpaSpecificationExecutor<Sight>`.

Secondly, the whole point of implementing `JPASpecificationExecutor` is to make use of the methods it provides. You should be calling the `findAll(Specification, Sort)` method, while filtering by `cityId` should be part of the specification.

Comment: I totally agree with you but what about when you want to use projections?

Comment: @IvanVilanculo Mixing projections and specifications is not supported, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692391/how-to-use-projections-and-specifications-with-spring-data-jpa